# Spring MVC Framework (Process from UI to Completing a Transaction)

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have begun some serious reading on this framework and i am seeing where and how DI is done. The examples i looked at showed me values that were hard coded and referenced but non really on from the UI to the database. I am wondering, just looking at the bigger picture here i was wondering in a real world application where this is actually integrated with an AJAX framework how is the information (user input) gets to the beans.

Tell me if i have this process correct is it that the java script makes a call to the container to find the function (through mapping), setters are used to set the bean (POJO) values for the classes from the user input, then the beans already being injected uses these values to preform the functions.I just want to be clear on the process and the roles of the various technologies of how the data gets from the UI to beans to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ajax request makes some http call. The spring XML (or annotations) maps the route to a controller. The URL parameters are decoded by spring and mapped (and optionally validated) into a command object (which was a param to the controller method). Then some db lookup and/or business logic happens. Since its an Ajax call you would normally return json which is generated by some mapping library (Jackson, gson, etc).

Comment: What about the values that come from the UI are they set using the class setters and then the beans take the values form there ? lets say like a bean has a property : p:username = "this should be a value the user entered". How will the bean get its value to pass into lets say a DAO Controller that looks up the username in the database. I understand the results can be pass back as JSON.

Comment: If its a form then the form inputs are converted to URL parameters

Comment: Its converted to URL parameters and passed to javascript or the spring beans?If to javascript what happens after that or if the spring beans does it get set first then used in the method?

Comment: I never used this before i am just trying to build up a clear picture on what happens so i can plan my coding

Comment: the url parameters are passed to the HTTP endpoint by the browser. Spring maps the URL to a controller, and maps URL parameters to the command object. To get a better idea of how this works, enable firebug in your browser and watch the network calls when you submit a form.